# Из-за чего сбилась кодировка при сборке JAR?

Tags: java, кодировка, jar, перекодировка

Здравствуйте!
Есть приложение написанное на Java. Парсит сайт и при необходимости отправляет email. При работе и запуске через Idea слова на русском языке передавались и отображались без изменений, при  сборке проекта и запуске Jar файла, русские слова превратились в "рандомную кашу". Где и что необходимо указать чтоб исправить эту проблему?

Comment: А как вы собираете приложение? Скорее всего просто не хватает флага кодировки, хотя если вы выводите русские буквы в консоль, то вот эта ссылка вам поможет: http://www.skipy.ru/technics/encodings.html

Comment: Собирал через стандартный инструмент Idea (Build Artifacts)

Comment: @IvanArchDev у вас `gradle` в качестве системы сборки? если да, то попробуйте где-нить указать кодировку явно. Тип как-то так: `compileOptions.encoding = 'utf-8'`

Comment: Нет, у меня в проекте Maven

Comment: @IvanArchDev тогда попробуйте так: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3018152/3212712

Comment: где слова превратились в кашу? при выводе на консоль? какая у вас ОС? добавьте pom.xml а вопрос.

Comment: разрабатываете и запускаете jar на одном компьютере/операционке?

Comment: Получаю данный с Вконтакте (сообщение) и его отправляю его по Email.
Когда запускаю программу в Idea, письмо приходит и с русским тестом всё в порядке.
Когда собираю Jar и запускаю эту программу на этом же самом компьютере (ОС Win10) то письма приходят со сбитой кодировкой.
Для отправки Email использую javax.mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась запуском JAR файла с применением дополнительного параметра для кодировки java -jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 file(название файла).jar